# Effectively set X-bits in a number N, starting from position P from MSB

Tags: c, bitset

The below code set X-bits in a number N starting position P from LSB (N is 32 bit Number)

```
//gcc 5.4.0
#include  <stdio.h>
unsigned int set_bits_pos(int N, int X, int P)
{
    unsigned int mask = ((1UL << X)-1) << P; 
    return (N|mask);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int bits = 3, pos=5, num=0x0F;       
    printf("0x%X\n", set_bits_pos(num,bits,pos));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xEF
```

How to convert the above function to set X-bits in number N, starting position P from MSB ? Best Possible way. Thanks

Edit: To Set from MSB and Arch Independent for both 32 & 64 bit N, after suggestions

```
//gcc 5.4.0
#include  <stdio.h>
size_t set_bits_pos(size_t N, int X, int P)
{
    size_t mask = ((1UL << X)-1) << ((8*sizeof(N)) - P - X); 
    return (N|mask);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t num=0x0F;
    int bits = 3, pos=5;       
    printf("0x%X\n", set_bits_pos(num,bits,pos));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x0700000F
```

Comment: What did you try so far and where are you stuck? First guess would be to replace `P` by `num_bits-P-X` and fine-tune for off-by-one errors

Comment: I tried like `((1UL << X)-1) << (32 - P - (X-1))` , which didn't gave proper answer. is there any best way to achieve it ?

Comment: "Didn't give proper answer" ist a bit vague. Please always show input data, expected output and what you got.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks,  `num_bits-P-X` is correct. Edited the question & expected answer.. But how to make it architecture independent ?

Comment: for me the code after editing does what you expect no ? in binary 00000111... so five 0 then three 1 as expected

Comment: @ThiruShetty It should be architecture independent. The only improvement I see is to use `uint_32` instead of `unsigned int` (which might be smaller on some platforms)

Comment: @bruno you are right but bit position from MSB side not from LSB

Comment: What about `(8*sizeof (N))` ? BTW: your return type should match the type of `N` I would assume.

Comment: @Gerhardh you mean use of `size_t` so that it will be arch independent ?

Comment: No. `size_t` is no more architectute independent than `int`. You could replace 32 by that formula to handle any size of input type.

Comment: What's the problem with `uint32_t`?

Comment: @Gerhardh #Ctx if the same code used for 64bit number on 64 bit arch.  `size_t` will not handle ??

Comment: For 32-bit use `uint32_t` and for 64-bit use `uint64_t`. Easy as that.

Comment: Then how to make it work for both 32 & 64 bit ??

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is not specified to be `8`. Also, integer types may contain padding bits, so `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT` is not necessarily the number of value bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the exact-width integer types:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t  set_low32(const uint32_t     value,
                    const unsigned int bits,
                    const unsigned int skip)
{
    uint32_t  mask = (~(uint32_t)0) >> (32 - bits);
    return value | (mask << skip);
}

uint64_t  set_low64(const uint64_t     value,
                    const unsigned int bits,
                    const unsigned int skip)
{
    uint64_t  mask = (~(uint64_t)0) >> (64 - bits);
    return value | (mask << skip);
}

uint32_t  set_high32(const uint32_t     value,
                     const unsigned int bits,
                     const unsigned int skip)
{
    uint32_t  mask = (~(uint32_t)0) << (32 - bits);
    return value | (mask >> skip);
}

uint64_t  set_high64(const uint64_t     value,
                     const unsigned int bits,
                     const unsigned int skip)
{
    uint64_t  mask = (~(uint64_t)0) << (64 - bits);
    return value | (mask >> skip);
}
```

`bits` is the number of bits to set (`X` in question), and `skip` is the number of low/high bits to skip (`P` in question).